# MongoDB - matching an array of string elements to single string element in a document

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB v3.6.5

I have a collection called "dealers" that hold documents which look like following examples below.

```
{
_id: 1
country: "France"
}

{
_id: 2
country: "Belgium"
}
```

I have an array of country values such as;

```
["France","Germany","Belgium"]
```

I want to retrieve all documents from dealers collection where it matches values between "country" property and array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$in` operator.

```
db.dealers.find( { "country" : { $in : [ "France", "Belgium" ] } } )
```